# get instagram posts with node js with instagram username

Tags: node.js, instagram

I am looking for ways to get users posts with graph instagram and node js but i could not find api to get another user posts with access token I only have access to my own posts with json data
it would be great if you show me best way

Answer (score 0):

might be a job for python just saying, it is definitely possible in js but as it seems, you will need to make EVERYTHING from 0 - 100, i recommend just using python for that

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , is there any famous library that could do this easily for me , it would be great if you send me links.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/download-instagram-posts-using-python-selenium-module/

here is a pretty good explanation of how to make it, what they are doing is making a python script that goes to Instagram and does it all automated, you do need to login since to view profiles on Instagram you have to be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this it may help a bit
[Link](https://rudrastyh.com/instagram/get-photos-with-javascript.html)

and this to take photos of any user [Link](https://rudrastyh.com/instagram/photos-without-token-wordpress.html)

Comment: unfortunately they are not working anymore because of instagram api update

Answer (score 0):

Try this node js library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-web-api#getphotosbyusernameparams

There is .getPhotosByUsername method which should work for you

Comment: unfortunately it is not working anymore , I tried this before I ask question but because of instagram updates something changed